# RaycastNonAlloc allocates 40B of memory in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to solve this for days and I can't find out what's wrong.

Here's a picture:
[image]

and here's a link to the unitypackage: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vm67njz5unn8w2/RaycastNonalloc.rar?dl=0

I have tested the project on two different computers and on both of them 40B of memory is allocated on the first RaycastNonAlloc. The second computer I tested this on had never had Unity installed and I just imported the package and ran the program without touching any settings. People that on the internet that have tried this do not get any allocated memory when running it. If someone could help me solve this I would be so happy I dunno what I will do.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Ray ray;
    public Transform targetTransform, targetTransform2,
        myTransform;
    public int numberOfRaycastHits;
    private RaycastHit[] raycastHits;
    private bool useOther;
    private float tempFloat;


    void Start()
    {
        raycastHits = new RaycastHit[10];
        myTransform = transform;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            useOther = !useOther;
            /*Material mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Diffuse"));
            Destroy(mat);*/
            //Debug.Log(numberOfRaycastHits);
            PerformRaycast();
        }
    }


    private void PerformRaycast()
    {
        if (useOther)
        {
            ray.origin = myTransform.position;
            ray.direction = targetTransform2.position - myTransform.position;
            numberOfRaycastHits = Physics.RaycastNonAlloc(ray, raycastHits, 10);
        }
        else
        {
            ray.origin = myTransform.position;
            ray.direction = targetTransform.position - myTransform.position;
            numberOfRaycastHits = Physics.RaycastNonAlloc(ray, raycastHits, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Are you profiling in editor or in device? (sometimes there is a difference)  Can you post the raycast script also so can have a look without importing package.

Comment: I get allocated memory in both the editor and standalone build.

Answer (score 3):

Unity got back to me with an answer that it's a bug. Thanks for the help guys.